# In a table containing rows of date ranges, from each row, generate one row per day containing hours of utilization

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given a table with rows like:

```
+----+-------------------------+------------------------+
| ID |        StartDate        |        EndDate         |
+----+-------------------------+------------------------+
|  1 | 2016-02-05 20:00:00.000 | 2016-02-07 5:00:00.000 |
+----+-------------------------+------------------------+
```

I want to produce a table like this:

```
+----+------------+----------+
| ID |    Date    | Duration |
+----+------------+----------+
|  1 | 2016-02-05 |        4 |
|  1 | 2016-02-06 |       24 |
|  1 | 2016-02-07 |        5 |
+----+------------+----------+
```

This is an interview-style question.  I am wondering how I can go about tackling this.  Is it possible to do this with just standard SQL query syntax?  Or is a procedural language like pl/pgSQL required to do a query like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is this:

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', dayhour) as dd,count(*)
FROM (VALUES (1, '2016-02-05 20:00:00.000'::timestamp, '2016-02-07 5:00:00.000'::timestamp)
     ) v(ID, StartDate, EndDate), lateral
    generate_series(StartDate, EndDate, interval '1 hour') g(dayhour) 
GROUP BY dd
ORDER BY dd;
```

That adds an extra hour, so this is more accurate:

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', dayhour) as dd,count(*)
FROM (VALUES (1, '2016-02-05 20:00:00.000'::timestamp, '2016-02-07 5:00:00.000'::timestamp)
     ) v(ID, StartDate, EndDate), lateral
    generate_series(StartDate, EndDate - interval '1 hour', interval '1 hour') g(dayhour) 
GROUP BY dd
ORDER BY dd;
```

Technically, the `lateral` is not needed (and in that case, I would replace the comma with `cross join`).  However, this is an example of a lateral join, so being explicit is good.

I should also note that the above is the simplest method.  However, the `group by` does slow down the query.  There are other methods that don't require generating a series for every hour.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to modify this to operate on a table of multiple entries. Just to check if I am understanding this correctly. I understand that the generate_series produces a table of timestamps based on the start/end/interval.  In general, the FROM clause would join the two tables.  Since the generate_series refers to specific columns in a row, it seems it is generating a table per row, and crossing just that row with the series generated from it?

Comment: @ddtemplar . . . Your understanding is correct.  In general in SQL, when you want to apply table function to each row, you are doing a "lateral join".  Postgres let's you do this without the "lateral" keyword.